# vba shape onchange event

Tags: excel, onchange, shapes, vba

I am currently having a problem with my excel vba script.
Basically I want some code to be tiggering by changing (deleting) a shape!

I do not know why the deleting of a shape is not triggering the Worksheet_Change event - can somebody help me with this?

Currently I do not even get the first messagebox when I click on the delete button of my keyboard..

```html
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    MsgBox "change"
    If TypeOf Selection Is Shape Then
        MsgBox "first area ok"
        shnames = SheetNames()
        If IsInArray(Selection.Name, shnames) Then
            MsgBox "if command is true"
            Application.OnKey Key:="{DEL}", Procedure:="delete_shape"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Thank you in advance for your reply!

BR, Rupert

Comment: Shapes do not expose any events. In fact, they react only to clicking (by virtue of `OnAction` property).

Comment: the strange thing is it was working until i closed the worksheet and i do not know what i changed or how it was working before?!

Comment: Your code reacts to pressing a `DEL` key - this is not an event exposed by shape. There's no connection between Worksheet_Change and shape deletion at all.

Comment: hm ok - is there a way to send the name of the shape to the userform if the same userform is triggered by  different shapes - so that i can delete it from the userform?